# $\{f_n\}$ sequence of holomorphic functions converges uniformly.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and  let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions $f_n:U\to \mathbb{C}$. Suppose this sequence is Cauchy with respect to the $L^2$ norm. Then $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $U$.

I have proved the following lemma.

*Let $0<s<R$, and assume $f$ is holomorphic on $\overline{D}(0,R)$. Then there exists constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that
$$
\|f\|_s\leq C_1\|f\|_{1,R}\leq C_2\|f\|_{2,R}
$$ whereby $\|\cdot\|_s$ is the $\sup$-norm on $\overline{D}(0,s)$ and $\|\cdot\|_{i,R}$ the $L^i$-norm on $\overline{D}(0,R)$ for $i=1,2$.*

Now, I want to use this lemma to prove my statement.

Let $V$ be a compact subset of $U$. I want to cover $V$ by a finite number of closed disks $\overline{D_i}(R_i,z_i)$ which I can make a little bigger such that they are still contained in $U$. How can I express this more foramlly? Then, if $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on each disk $\overline{D_i}$ does it converge uniformly on $U$?

Comment: Maybe you can take an exhaustion of compacta, that is a sequence $(K_n)$ of compacta such that $K_n\subset K_n^\circ$ and $\bigcup_n K_n=U$.

Comment: How would that be useful in this case?

Comment: Take $K_n:=\overline{D(0.n)}\cap U$.So you should only prove convergence over every $K_n$, because any oher compac set of $U$ is contained on some $K_n$.

Comment: You mean $K_n:=\overline{D(0,n)}\cap U$? Otherwise it is not compact

Comment: Is uniform convergence of a sequence of functions heriditary by taking subspaces?

Comment: $U$ at the end should be $V?$

Comment: Yes I am sorry, I meant $V$